# Is there an expression for a function that maps integers to one and non-integers to zero?

Tags: functions

Is there a function that can be built with addition, multiplication, exponentiation, trigonometric functions, integrals, (and all of their inverses i.e subtraction, division, taking logarithms, $\arcsin(x)$, derivatives, etc) that would take an integer and output $1$ and take a non-integer and output $0$?

I looked at the Dirichlet Function but it separated rationals from irrationals, and the only solution that I could come up with was with the Fourier Series of $$x-\lfloor x \rfloor = \frac 12 - \frac 1\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1k \sin (2 \pi k x)$$
But this uses infinite series. Is there a way to build such a function? If there is not, why not?

Comment: It's trivial. Just take the left side of what you have in your formula above and call 1 iff it is 0, 0 otherwise.

Comment: For your example, do you mean $1 - (\lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor)$ instead of $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$?  The latter is a sawtooth wave not an indicator function for the integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is cheating, but I don't think it's possible otherwise, since all of the other functions are continuous and a composition of continuous functions is continuous, integrals preserve continuity too, and even though differentiation doesn't in general, all of the functions you listed are not just continuous but analytic or infinitely differentiable so their derivatives are continuous as well at all orders.  Anyway, here is my example:

$f(x) = 0^{\sin(\pi \cdot x)^2}$

For this to be correct you have to define $0^0=1$ which is not an unreasonable choice, but usually this expression is left undefined.

Comment: Wow, that is a really clever answer, I know I did not mention limits as possible building blocks for the function, but would $f(x) = \lim_{n \to x} 0^{\sin(\pi n)^2}$ be an equivalent statement to the one you gave?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that function is identically $0$ (regardless of how one defines $0^0$), for example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+goes+to+0+of+0%5E(sin(pi+x)%5E2)

Comment: Is allowing limits the same as allowing derivatives?

Comment: Yes, I think that in some twisted way allowing limits is the same thing as allowing derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply defined as an infinite product
$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos^{2n}(\frac{\tau x}{2})$$
Where $\tau=2\pi$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You could explain in your answer why this function is an answer to the question (it is not obvious to me).

Answer (score -1):

Well.. you can always built it as a distribution:

$$
\Upsilon(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 ~~~ \text{for} ~~~ x\in\mathbb{N}
\\
0 ~~~ \text{for} ~~~x\not\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}
$$

lol

Comment: I think "built with" means composition of functions.

Comment: Also allowed are applications of integrals and derivatives...  But I don't see how that can be used to contruct an if-then statement, I explained why in my answer.

Comment: (Also, this isn't what is usually meant by the word 'distribution'; the standard terminology is "piecewise function")

Comment: I just wanted to give a funny answer >.<